# How to sort user contact array in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, mobile-application

I am new in react native and I need to design screen same as shown in the image below

[image: User Contact Sorting]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Could you please provide some details and uptil now what have you tried and where you are facing the difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same as how you do it in javascript...

```
  let Array2 = Array1.sort((a, b) => {
  let nameA = a.toLowerCase(), nameB = b.toLowerCase()
  if (nameA < nameB)
    return -1
  if (nameA > nameB)
     return 1
     return 0 
})
```

better to learn js before starting react-native

Comment: I not sure how can i implement alphabetical vertical view and how to get data on each alphabet click like right side 

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array, just use the < > or == to sort for strings, A < B, and C > B. You can use a compare function passed into array.sort.